# Proof of existence of optimal strategy in $2\times 2$ zero-sum game.

Tags: game-theory

I am trying to solve the following task and don't know where to start from:

> Given that in a  $2\times 2$  matrix zero-sum game the first player has optimal
>   pure strategy, prove that the second has optimal pure strategy too.

I am sorry if it is stupid question, but I find game theory quite hard.

Comment: By "optimal strategy" do you mean "equilibrium strategy"? In general, optimality for player 1 depends on what player 2 does.

Answer (score 0):

If player 1 has a pure strategy as his optimal strategy, then player 2 will know this and respond accordingly. So whatever his best response is he will do every time the game is played. He therefore has a pure strategy too. Simple.